# render the returned data from rails controller via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json

In rails application, i am trying to fetch few records using a Ajax/jQuery, am getting the right data but the problem how do i parse the returned data and render it as HTML?

my js function

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/questions/retrieve_function",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
            'obsolete': 1
    },
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            alert(key + ", " + $.param(value));
        });

    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    },
    type: 'GET'
});
```

my controller method:

```
def retrieve_function
 obsolete = params[:obsolete]
 @values = values.find(:all, :conditions => ["obsolete = ?", obsolete])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render :json => @values }
  end
end
```

am using $.param currently to check whether am getting correct values, any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Update

The format returned

```
"[[
  {\"question\":{\"created_at\":\"2011-09-26T12:56:41Z\",\"choicea\":\"dg<br>\",\"qtype\":\"multiple\",\"title\":\"dfgdfg<br>\",\"choiceb\":\"dg<br>\",\"updated_at\":\"2011-10-10T14:41:52Z\",\"choicec\":\"dfg<br>\",\"choiced\":\"dg<br>\",\"id\":50,\"hint\":\"dg<br>\",\"obsolete\":1,\"correctans\":\"C\"}}

]]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there should be just one bracket in your json format you have to change your server code like that. And then u can use this function to get your values from json

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    alert(key+" - "+value.question.title + " - "+value.question.created_at+" ...")
})
```

Comment: actually even am confused about that Sedat, let me inspect and post the format.

Comment: Im waiting for your format. maybe u can use this in your success method : alert(JSON.stringify(data)) to learn your format that returned from server

Comment: i have posted the format, i would need json2 plugin for stringify right?

Comment: i checked the returned format at jsonlint found its invalid json

Comment: i have converted the returned data to json by using to_json now i get the following format

Comment: can u add alert(JSON.stringify(data)) in your success function and share that text here? also i tried something like this maybe will help your if not pls share that text from alert http://jsfiddle.net/G46Nm/3/

Comment: actually sedat its not one record its multiple records like i have thre questions within those their respective contents.

Comment: no matter.. that function will get each questions item in your data array. check this out http://jsfiddle.net/G46Nm/4/

Comment: np i hope, that will help you :)

Comment: i think that is very close i need to do some minor tweaks in the json string dats it., i have marked the answers accepted and +1

Comment: ty if there is problem let me know cya

Comment: hi sedat am doing this but no alert... 
var datajson = JSON.stringify(data);
                datajson = datajson.replace(']', '');
                datajson = datajson.replace('[', '');
                
                $.each(datajson,function(key,value){
                    alert(key + " - " + value.question.title )
                });

Comment: u parse your json to string and then u trying to make $.each on string, this is wrong. And .replace() will change both brackets to '' i guess it shouldnt be. there should be just one bracket. And after your replace is done use this var json = JSON.parse(datajson) and then make $.each(json,function....

Comment: yeah u right even i was thinking that, i think i need to get rid of those square brackets at server side itself